# Why is this css not responsing to external image source?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

So I am trying to practice css and for some reason this code will not respond to the image links I am putting in. I tried multiple links from different sources and nothing works. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? The image is for the showcase area at the bottom half of the css code.

I have tried background-image: url(....) and background: url(....)

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f52626a245.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo Narrow' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<!---Navbar-->
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Website</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
  </div>


<!---Showcase-->
  <div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am John Doe</h1>
    <p>And I'm a Photographer</p>
    <button>Hire me</button>
  </div>
</div>






</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

css

```
  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow'; font-size: 18px;;
  }
  
  .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #034f84;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color:#034f84;
  }
  
  .topnav a.active {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
    .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }


  /* showcase */

  .hero-image {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)) ;
    background:url(http://placekitten.com/200/300) no-repeat 0 0;
    
    height: 50%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .hero-text {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
  }
  
  .hero-text button {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #ddd;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .hero-text button:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
  }
```

javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined, height of `hero-image` as 50%. Change that to some defined value say `height: 500px;`. Because percentage height always takes the height of parent if defined. Since the parent element `body` doesnot have a defined value, the height in percentage for child will not work.

**Option 1:** Changing `position` of `.hero-text` to `relative`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow';
  font-size: 18px;
  ;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #034f84;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #034f84;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }

  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }

  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* showcase */

.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  background-image: url(https://cdn-media.theathletic.com/cdn-cgi/image/fit=cover,width=700,height=466/A3gFprxfg737_evEgJW15MGsl_1440x.960.jpg);

  height: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.hero-text button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-text button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!---Navbar-->
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Website</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>


<!---Showcase-->
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am John Doe</h1>
    <p>And I'm a Photographer</p>
    <button>Hire me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Option 2:** Changing height of `.hero-image` to pre defned value

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow';
  font-size: 18px;
  ;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #034f84;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #034f84;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }

  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }

  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/* showcase */

.hero-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300) no-repeat 0 0;

  height: 500px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.hero-text button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-text button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!---Navbar-->
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Website</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>
<!---Showcase-->
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am John Doe</h1>
    <p>And I'm a Photographer</p>
    <button>Hire me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the above fiddle aswell you are using height in percentage for `hero-image`

Answer (score 0):

it's simple, `background-image` represents the image for the background. noy to style it. just change  `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));` to `background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/200/300);`

and to style it: `background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));`

**This should work**